# Knapsack 0/1 algorithm - unlimited resources

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I've run into a thinking trouble and I'm just frustrated. I have a working algorithm of the knapsack problem, using dynamic programming, where I specify

- Max load
- Items (their weight)

and the algorithm calculates the optimal fill of the knapsack using those items. But now I need to fill it *completely*, using *least* items, but I have unlimited amount of each item. (Those items have weights `{1; w1; w2; ...}` so it is always possible to complete).

How do I fit this in the 'classic' algorithm?

Thanks

Comment: this prob is equivalent to Coin change prob http://people.csail.mit.edu/bdean/6.046/dp/ follow the link for more dynamic programming probs

Comment: That actually seems exactly like it, yeah. But the links at the page you provided open only a blank window :/ Thanks anyway though

Comment: Nevermind, I typed the address pointed to by the JS command myself. It can be found at http://people.csail.mit.edu/bdean/6.046/dp/dp_2.swf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

- M    = Amount need to fill
- w[]  = Array of weights
- dp[] = Array of optimal fill(dp[i] contains minimum number of items needed to fill weight i).

```
 initialize the dp array with INFINITY, dp[0] = 0;
 for(i = 0;i<size of w;i++) {
    for(j = 1;j<=M;j++) {
       if(j-w[i] >= 0) {
          dp[j] = min(dp[j], dp[j-w[i]]+1);
       }
    }
 }

 final solution is the value of dp[M];
```